# Chrome giving me an error on the JS console: "Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: The string contains invalid characters."

Tags: javascript

It is pointing me to line

```
var T = document.createElement("table id=&quot;"+tableID+"&quot;");
```

in which I was trying to create a table element with a particular ID. Any idea what happened? I thought I made a proper escape sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Some IE versions let you have a full tag inside of of document.create, but standards following browsers only accept the tag name.  To set the id, you can either set the attribute directly or use `setAttribute`.

```
var T = document.createElement("table");
T.id=tableID;
```

or

```
var T = document.createElement("table");
T.setAttribute("id", tableID);
```

Answer (score 1):

The invalid character here is space. `document.createElement` only takes the element name as the argument, and element names can not contain spaces. So you should create the elemnt first, then set its attributes/properties.

```
var T = document.createElement('table');
T.id = tableID
```